# (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in CheckersgameWeb.GamesChannel.handle_in/3

Tags: elixir

I'm currently building a checkers game in phoenix that's hitting into a "FunctionClauseError". The error is being thrown by my "handle_in" function in the games channel which I've provided here:

```
def handle_in("click", %{"click" => ll}, socket) do
    IO.puts("whatever")
end
```

Any ideas as to what we're doing wrong?

Comment: What's in the function clause error? It sounds like `handle_in/3` is getting called with different arguments. Are you handling the general case there?

Comment: Could you post more details about the error message? As pointed out above, it sounds like a function is being invoked with different arguments than it accepts. I don't think the problem is with the `click` function, because you're passing 2 arguments in every call that's shown. But it could be in `handle_in` if it's being called with something other than `"click"` or a map that doesn't contain the `"click"` key.

Comment: The error is not caused by `handle_in`, but by the code that calls handle in. I edited your question to remove the unrelated information. Please post the full errror message and the code that calls `handle_in`.

Comment: Change it like this to debug `def handle_in("click", payload, socket), do: IO.puts(payload)`

`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```elixir
defmodule Example do
  def run() do
    Demo.handle_in("UNEXPECTED", "foo", "bar")
  end

  def handle_in("click", map, socket) do
    IO.puts("whatever")
  end
end
```

And here's the error message when we call `run/0`:

```elixir
iex(1)> Example.run
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Example.handle_in/3

    The following arguments were given to Example.handle_in/3:

        # 1
        "UNEXPECTED"

        # 2
        "foo"

        # 3
        "bar"
```

You can see from this output, that `run/1` calls `handle_in/3` with `"UNEXPECTED"` as its first argument. There is no clause of `handle_in` that expects that, so elixir generates the error. A common way to handle this if you can't control the inputs is to add a catch-all clause that does not pattern-match the arguments:

```elixir
def handle_in("click", map, socket) do
  IO.puts("clicked")
end

def handle_in(one, two, three) do
  IO.puts("Called with: #{inspect one}, #{inspect two}, #{inspect three}")
end
```

Now the error is not produced, because the second clause can handle the `"UNEXPECTED"` string:

```elixir
iex(1)> Example.run
Called with: "UNEXPECTED", "foo", "bar"
:ok
```

In your case, it could be that the `"click"` string is not passed, or that the 2nd argument isn't a map that contains the `"click"` key, but without the calling code or error message, it's impossible to tell.